# Finding multiple combinations of sums in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Ive been trying to make something in Excel to find multiple combinations of sums.

I have list of numbers that needs to be added together to be either within ranges of 500-510 or 450-460.

Only two numbers from the list can be used to find the sum. the numbers can not be used more than once. and giving the combinations of multiple results would be great. and if a number is not used it is ok.

I've tried the solver add-in and some other tips I found from this site but could not find something that gives multiple answers.

Does anyone know if this will be possible?

Comment: If you can only use two numbers then a "brute force"  nested loop should work fine.  How many numbers in your list?

Comment: It varies time to time but up to 14 numbers

Answer (score 3):

I'd break this into 2 tasks. First would be to simply generate all of the index pairs to test in the input array.  That's relatively simple with recursive procedure. This one uses a private `Type` to store the pairs, but it could adapted to use some other method of storing the pairs:

```
Private Type Tuple
    ValueOne As Long
    ValueTwo As Long
End Type

Private Sub FindCombinations(elements As Long, ByRef results() As Tuple, _
                             Optional ByVal iteration As Long = 0)
    If iteration = 0 Then ReDim results(0)
    Dim idx As Long
    For idx = iteration To elements - 1
        Dim combo As Tuple
        With combo
            .ValueOne = iteration
            .ValueTwo = idx
        End With
        results(UBound(results)) = combo
        If iteration <> elements And idx <> elements Then
            ReDim Preserve results(UBound(results) + 1)
        End If
    Next

    If iteration < elements Then FindCombinations elements, results, iteration + 1
End Sub
```

Then, you use a "entry-point" procedure to generate the index combinations, use those to index into your source array, and apply your selection criteria:

```
Private Sub FindMatchingSets(testSet() As Long)
    Dim indices() As Tuple
    FindCombinations UBound(testSet) + 1, indices

    Dim idx As Long, results() As Tuple

    For idx = LBound(indices) To UBound(indices)
        Dim tupleSum As Long
        tupleSum = testSet(indices(idx).ValueOne) + testSet(indices(idx).ValueTwo)
        If indices(idx).ValueOne <> indices(idx).ValueTwo And _
           ((tupleSum >= 500 And tupleSum <= 510) Or _
           (tupleSum >= 450 And tupleSum <= 460)) Then
            Debug.Print testSet(indices(idx).ValueOne) & " + " & _
                testSet(indices(idx).ValueTwo) & " = " & tupleSum
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It isn't clear what you intend to *do* with the results, so this simply outputs the calculated values to the Immediate Window. Example calling code:

```
Private Sub Example()
    Dim test(4) As Long
    test(0) = 100
    test(1) = 200
    test(2) = 250
    test(3) = 260
    test(4) = 400

    FindMatchingSets test
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

May modify it according to your need & try

```
Sub test()
Dim X, Y, TRw, GotNum, First, Second As Long
TRw = 1
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
For X = 1 To 100                   ' assumed col A1 to A100 is the list
GotNum = .Cells(X, 1).Value
    If (GotNum >= 450 And GotNum <= 460) Or (GotNum >= 500 And GotNum <= 510) Then
    .Cells(X, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    First = GotNum
        For Y = X + 1 To 100
        GotNum = .Cells(Y, 1).Value
            If (GotNum >= 450 And GotNum <= 460) Or (GotNum >= 500 And GotNum <= 510) Then
            Second = GotNum
            TRw = TRw + 1
            .Cells(TRw, 3).Value = First     ' write 1st Number in Col C
            .Cells(TRw, 4).Value = Second    ' write 2nd Number in Col D
            .Cells(TRw, 5).Value = First + Second   ' write Sum of 1st & 2nd in Col C
            End If
        Next Y
    End If
Next X
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your question needs to be a little clearer in terms of what your expected output is (do you want a list of combos, or just to see the results?), but here's my solution.

[image: combination of sums - potential solution]

I've put a list of 20 numbers in column Y, and assigned them all a letter (a through to t) in column X

Then I've built a matrix of the combinations of a to t, and have entered the following formula (the below is for cell C3, but it can be copied and pasted into all parts of the matrix)

`=IF(C$2=$B3,"x",VLOOKUP(C$2,$X:$Y,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($B3,$X:$Y,2,FALSE))`

I've then used conditional formatting to set the colour of the cells if they meet your criteria for the sum - you can do this by highlighting all the sums (cell C3:V22) and going to

home / conditional formatting / new rule...

picking the rule type **format only cells that contain**

and then in the drop down menus picking **Cell Value** / **Between** / *Your high range*

and then selecting a format (fill background colour, usually)

Do this once for the "high" sum, and once for the "low" sum. You can make the colours the same or different, depending on what you want to see.

I've also for reference included a reference to what the number is in Row 1 and column A. The formula for row 1 is (example is for C1, but it can be copied across)

`=VLOOKUP(C2,$X:$Y,2,FALSE)`

And the formula for column A is (example for A3) `=VLOOKUP(B3,$X:$Y,2,FALSE)`

The advantage of this approach is that it's all in excel (no code required), but the disadvantage is that it's hard to get a list of results. You *could* use a different formula to just return the sum (e.g. return the text "205+298") when it meets one of the conditions, but then it's still a pain to get it out of the matrix format and into a single list. Much easier using VBA